# OpenShift and persistent Redis config

Tags: docker, redis, openshift, kubernetes, redhat

I have successfully deployed [Redis (persistent)](https://github.com/sclorg/redis-container/tree/master/3.2) image on my OpenShift installation. Now I want to persist the Redis configuration, and I have followed [this](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-example-configuring-redis) instructions.

However, the Redis is started with this command inside a container:
`/opt/rh/rh-redis32/root/usr/bin/redis-server *:6379`

I see that it [should be started with the first argument](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) as a path to the configuration file in order to configure itself on startup.

How can I achieve this in OpenShift?

Comment: Hey, did you create a configmap with your config file?

Comment: Yes, I created it as it was explained in the OpenShift documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue with run commands specified in deployment config:

```
 containers:
        - name: redis
          image: >-
            centos/redis-32-centos7@sha256:7289ff47dd1c5bd24e6eefaf18cfbacf5ad68c0768f1b727a79c026bbef5a038
          command:
            - /opt/rh/rh-redis32/root/usr/bin/redis-server
            - /redis-master/redis.conf
```

Since this completly overrides default startup behaviof of the provided Docker image I had to add dir and requirepass configs to my config map:

```
dir /var/lib/redis/data
requirepass srid
maxmemory 2mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Comment: Smart,I didn't know "--daemonize no" was a default value! it made me give you that bad answer, cause my args were "/tmp/redis.conf --daemonize no'" and it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are supposed to try that kind of stuff ;) 
But you can use that workaround (not using it in production could be a good idea)

First of all create download your config file :

```
$ curl -o redis.conf http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf
$ curl -o run-redis https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sclorg/redis-container/master/3.2/root/usr/bin/run-redis
```

Then edit redis.conf and change the values you want

```
$ vi redis.conf
```

Now edit run-redis and replace last line with :

> exec ${REDIS_PREFIX}/bin/redis-server /tmp/redis.conf --daemonize no
>   "$@" 2>&1

```
$ vi run-redis
```

Now you have to create a configMap from these files :

```
$ oc create configmap myredisconfig --from-file=redis.conf --from-file=run-redis
```

And mount the configmap into the container:

```
$ oc volume dc/redis --add --name=conf --type=configmap --configmap-name=myredisconfig --mount-path=/tmp
```

Finally edit redis dc:

*Let's suppose I changed port 6379 to port 5000 in my redis.conf*

- Add spec.template.spec.containers.command :

> ```
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - command:
>     - /tmp/run-redis
> ```

- Change spec.template.spec.volumes.configMap.defaultMode to 444

> ```
>   - configMap:
>       defaultMode: 444
>       name: myredisconfig
>     name: conf
> ```

- If you are using an image with healthchecks, don't forget to change ports to check with your new one, or it will fail (spec.template.spec.containers.livenessProbe.tcpSocket.port)

> ```
>     livenessProbe:
>       failureThreshold: 3
>       initialDelaySeconds: 30
>       periodSeconds: 10
>       successThreshold: 1
>       tcpSocket:
>         port: 5000
> ```

- Now change the readinessProbe adding "-p $PORT" in test command :

> ```
>     readinessProbe:
>       exec:
>         command:
>         - /bin/sh
>         - -i
>         - -c
>         - test "$(redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5000 -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping)" == "PONG"
> ```

- Don't forget to change ContainerPort: 6379 with you new port, or you won't be able to expose it to services & routes (spec.template.spec.ports)

> ```
>  ports:
>     - containerPort: 5000
>       protocol: TCP
> ```

```
$ oc edit dc redis
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but I figured out a cleaner why to do it.